# Switching between 2 options

Tags: c#, if-statement

So i have 2 Mouse clicks. I need to make them change with each other every time code goes from start to goto Start. Its hard to explain but here is some code:

```
Start:
//some clicks 
LeftClick1(x,y)
LeftClick2(x,y)
//some clicks
goto Start;
```

I want to achieve something like this:

```
    //some clicks 
    LeftClick1(x,y)
    //some clicks
    LeftClick2(x,y)
    //some clicks
    LeftClick1(x,y)
    //some clicks
     LeftClick2(x,y)
```

Its like never ending loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `while` loop:

```
while(true)
{
   //some clicks 
   LeftClick1(x,y)
   //some clicks
   LeftClick2(x,y)
   //some clicks
   LeftClick1(x,y)
   //some clicks
   LeftClick2(x,y)
}
```

But you should break the loop in somewhere manually.